# Azure Point-to-Site VPN auth logging

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-security

I have multiple VNets in my Azure environment and they all have P2S VPN set up. It works, users authenticates with certificates. Now, how can I enable logging for successful and failed authn for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Azure P2S VPN doesn't support the audit yet. There is an official site that users can post their feedback. Someone has already requested the same feature on it:

[Provide auditing capabilities for Point to Site VPN](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/5314765-provide-auditing-capabilities-for-point-to-site-vp)

You may try to up vote it on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnostics configs are not visible from the Network Gateway section, you can enable it by going to the generic `Monitor` section. From the Left blade go to `Diagnostic Settings` > find the Virtual Network Gateway that your using for your Point-to-Site VPN. Enable the Tunnel Diagnostic Logs (and any others you want), send them to a Log Analytics Workspace.
[image]